Advice on Fixing Swinging Glass Shower Door?
My girlfriend and I came home last night to find our glass shower door off its hinges. The door didn’t break, thankfully, but it did slip out. I recently moved into the house so not really sure what would have caused it.
From what I can tell, the door must have slipped out of the track/hinge from being loosened. I’m no shower expert so please correct me if I’m wrong. To me, it looks like it’s just three components: the glass door, the track it fell out of, and the rubber thingamajig track that helps keep it in place.
Has anyone else dealt with a similar issue? I’m looking for any advice on how to securely reattach the door, or if there are any online resources yall know of. considering I am not sure what everything is even called I have been struggle bussing to find a resource.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!


Here are a few pictures for reference:
Top of Track 
Bottom of Track 
Glass Door in current state
Only part that looks a little wonky


I wonder if that black bit on the right of the glass is bonded to the glass, and that it basically adds a bit of width to that edge fo the glass.  So when slipped into the track, the track retains it.  So maybe the track just loosened up a bit, and using some pliers (I'd use vise grips with some cardboard in the jaws) to tighten the track a bit, maybe you can slip the glass back in the track.  Assuming you can figure out how to remove the track.

Adhesive bond holding the glass has failed. You are lucky that it did not fall when a person or a beloved pet animal was in the way. You could try to contact the mfgr and ask what adhesive would make a secure bond.

I would put a bead of clear mildew resistant silicone into the back of the dry glazing, put the dry glazing back on the glass and allow it to cure.
Put a small bead of clear mildew resistant silicone on both sides of the track and reinsert the glass into the track and allow it to cure.
It is very difficult to maintain the appearance of the track by squeezing the tracks together to increase the friction.

I appreciate the advice. Silicone is what I ended up using and so far so good but I guess only time will tell. Definitely should have had two people though to do it because that was tricky and I didn't even think about using suction to hold it up

depending on the type, you might be lucky.
It might be just off the track.
The top part has a rail for the wheels.
Glass door is very heavy so it might take two to fix it.
Lift it back in the top track.

There is no top track. The door swings off of hinges on the LHS.
